# C# How to traverse a subtree with recursion?

Tags: c#, xml, recursion, linq-to-xml

I guess, I have to set first the starting point which I want to explore the subtree, then build a recursive call.

Example:

```
<realRoot>
  <node>
    <desiredRoot>
      <rootChild/>
        <nestedChild/>
      <rootChild/>
    </desiredRoot>
  </node>
 </realRoot>
```

My goal is to iterate only:

```
<desiredRoot>
      <rootChild/>
        <nestedChild/>
      <rootChild/>
</desiredRoot>
```

What's the best solution in C# to do so?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Look at the `Descendants` method in LINQ to XML.  This should be pretty trivial to work out if you look at some examples.

Comment: See response to following posting.  The solution uses a recursive method for reading the xml : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491166/parse-xml-to-treeview-list

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly: A simple example display the names and types of elements:

```
            var xmlstr = @"<realRoot>
  <node>
    <desiredRoot>
      <rootChild/>
      <nestedChild/>
      <rootChild/>
    </desiredRoot>
  </node>
 </realRoot>";
            var xd = XDocument.Parse(xmlstr);
            var el = xd.Root.Element("node").Descendants();
            foreach (var x in el)
                Console.WriteLine("{0} [{1}]", x.Name, x.NodeType);
```

Print:

```
desiredRoot [Element]
rootChild [Element]
nestedChild [Element]
rootChild [Element]
```

Link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BIE0zI