# how to retrieve nodes from xml file in mvc

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, treeview, nodes

```
public JsonResult ddllistvalue(string datafeedid)
{
    Session["ddlvalue"] = datafeedid;
    return Json(db.PopulateProgramddl(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public void readxml()
{
    lobtype = Convert.ToString(Session["ddlvalue"]);
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(Server.MapPath(@"\Files\" + lobtype + ".xml"));
    TreeNode treenode = Node;
    XmlNode xmlnode = Node.DataItem;
    if (xmlnode.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        if (xmlnode.Attributes != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < xmlnode.Attributes.Count; i++)
            {
                TreeNode childnode = new TreeNode(
                    "@" + xmlnode.Attributes[i].Name,
                    "@" + xmlnode.Attributes[i].Name);
                treenode.ChildNodes.Add(childnode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

generate xml treeview from xml file in mvc4 using razor.please save me from this problem..error is :The name 'Node' does not exist in the current context.iam facicng the problem with 'node'

Comment: `TreeNode treenode = Node;` This statement causes problem, verify where `Node` is initialized because it is not available in your controller that's why Visual studio giving you an error.

Comment: i accept u r answer..but in this code how to assign treenode in mvc controller brother..

Comment: You should visit this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491166/parse-xml-to-treeview-list) or [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-treeview-with-asp-net-mvc-4/) to get some idea about treeView.